# getting a list of users and how much they have bought from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with user data like following:

```
|--user id--|--registration_date--|--voucher campaign--|--transaction id--|--price--|--purchase date--|
|--5433126--|--   2015-05-23    --|--     tlp05      --|--68536116696879--|--18.00--|--   2015-05-23--|
|--5433126--|--   2015-05-23    --|--     tlp05      --|--68435132139899--|-- 7.00--|--   2015-05-29--|
|--9865313--|--   2015-06-01    --|--     zig15      --|--97889200016487--|--23.00--|--   2015-06-15--|
|--7879463--|--   2015-05-27    --|--     tlp10      --|--      NaN     --|-- NaN --|--      NaN    --|
...
```

I want to make an additional column which would contain a string telling me about users overall shopping activity:

`Never` if user never bought anything;

`Once` if user only bought something once;

`Multiple` if user bought something multiple times;

so my desired result would be like this:

```
|--user id--|--registration_date--|--voucher campaign--|--transaction id--|--price--|--purchase date--|--activity--|
|--5433126--|--   2015-05-23    --|--     tlp05      --|--68536116696879--|--18.00--|--   2015-05-23--|--Multiple--|
|--5433126--|--   2015-05-23    --|--     tlp05      --|--68435132139899--|-- 7.00--|--   2015-05-29--|--Multiple--|
|--9865313--|--   2015-06-01    --|--     zig15      --|--97889200016487--|--23.00--|--   2015-06-15--|--    Once--|
|--7879463--|--   2015-05-27    --|--     tlp10      --|--      NaN     --|-- NaN --|--      NaN    --|--   Never--|
...
```

What would be most efficient way to achieve this without simply looping over the whole dataframe spliting it by user id and checking if there were any purchases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count number of non missing values per groups of column `purchase date` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `sum` to helper Series and set new values by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
s = df['purchase date'].notna().groupby(df['user id']).transform('sum')
df['activity'] = np.select([s == 0, s == 1], ['Never','Once'], default='Multiple')
print (df)
   user id registration_date voucher campaign  transaction id  price  \
0  5433126        2015-05-23            tlp05    6.853612e+13   18.0   
1  5433126        2015-05-23            tlp05    6.843513e+13    7.0   
2  9865313        2015-06-01            zig15    9.788920e+13   23.0   
3  7879463        2015-05-27            tlp10             NaN    NaN   

  purchase date  activity  
0    2015-05-23  Multiple  
1    2015-05-29  Multiple  
2    2015-06-15      Once  
3           NaN     Never
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
Name: purchase date, dtype: float64
```

Similar idea with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary and replace not matched missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['activity'] = s.map({0:'Never', 1:'Once'}).fillna('Multiple')
print (df)
   user id registration_date voucher campaign  transaction id  price  \
0  5433126        2015-05-23            tlp05    6.853612e+13   18.0   
1  5433126        2015-05-23            tlp05    6.843513e+13    7.0   
2  9865313        2015-06-01            zig15    9.788920e+13   23.0   
3  7879463        2015-05-27            tlp10             NaN    NaN   

  purchase date  activity  
0    2015-05-23  Multiple  
1    2015-05-29  Multiple  
2    2015-06-15      Once  
3           NaN     Never
```

Answer (score 2):

Another try using ternary:

```
import numpy as np

df["activity"] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['transactionid']), "Never", 
                          np.where(df.groupby('userid')['userid'].transform('count') > 1, 
                                   "Multiple", "Once")
                         )
```